Need date between function
I have 5 session between two date table name ABC



SESS-ID
DATE-1
DATE-2




1
01-Mar-2001
30-Mar-2002


2
01-Mar-2003
30-Mar-2004


3
01-Mar-2005
30-Mar-2006


4
01-Mar-2007
30-Mar-2008


5
01-Mar-2009
30-Mar-2010



enter image description here
enter image description here
Kindly provide me with a query idea to retrieve the correct SESS-ID for the date 13-May-2002 in Oracle 11G.

I need a lot of things too, but would never ask for help like this. Have you searched "working with dates" in oracle documentation? What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Try this one:
select *
from your_table
where DATE '2002-05-13' BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2

